# CVS Repository for BPEL in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, eclipse-plugin, bpel

I tried to create a CVS repository in eclipse as guided by http://www.eclipse.org/bpel/users/pdf/HelloWorld-BPELDesignerAndODE.pdf for using BPEL .But i am unable to proceed.
The error is

> Error Validating location:"Could not connect to :pserver:anonymous@dev.eclipse.org:/cvroot/technology:Cannot locate host:dev.eclipse.org"

What might be the cause for this error and what is the solution ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to create a CVS repository, you need to do that on your own CVS server.

Comment: Speed reading that document (which BTW is pretty old), you want to connect to the Eclipse CVS. Eclipse moved to GIT a while ago.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I gave the same credentials as mentioned in the pdf link even then i am getting same error... can u please guide me to create my own cvs server to succedd as in pdf file ?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel : GIT ? I am newbie about this, so what changes should i make to procceedd ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse has moved to Git and has shut down anonymous access to the CVS servers.  The repo you want can be seen at [BPEL](http://git.eclipse.org/c/bpel/org.eclipse.bpel.git/).  You can get the Git URLs from there.  Then you can either install EGit and use the [User Guide](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide) to get it, or use one of the many Git command line clients.